# Common python config file across Bitbucket repositories

Tags: python, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a python config file that will be used by all the respositories in my project - Bitbucket (Server).

I don't want to keep a copy of that config file in each repos to avoid maintaining multiple file for every change.

I don't have python artefact repository so I can't put that config file in a library.
I don't want to put the config file in public artefact repositories.

Is there a way to import python file(s) from another bitbucket repositories?

Comment: Why dont you put it in a central repo like AWS S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly: put your common code in a separate repository, and then add that repository as a git submodule whenever you need it.  You'll have to checkout recursively or run `git submodule init --update`, though, to get the submodule checkout out.

## References

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Great! That's what I'm looking for. thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept if this really does answer the question :)